# Additional fields for Registration signup in Securesocial

Tags: playframework-2.0, scala-2.10, securesocial

I am using with playframework and I find it's a pain.

I need to add additional fields such as age, Gender, country etc while signup.

Registration controller is a object and cannot be extended. Tried writing a new controller for Registration, but becomes nasty.

Any nicer way todo this ?

Comment: No I don't think you can. See

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197019/how-to-add-extra-field-in-signup-form-of-scala-securesocial

Answer (score 0):

Latest changes in master - what will become version 3.0 - let you override/replace the built in controllers easily now. The controllers are defined using traits and are managed and DI friendly now.

You can either override them or take them out and put your own implementations if they need to be really different to what comes out of the box.